# Converting 8-length varchar to datetime

Tags: sql, converters

I have varchar column as dataset as:

```
20110712
20141229
20100222
20140408
20131117
20130912
20140702
20110405
```

That need to be converted datetime datatypes. I have tried: CONVERT(date, column_name) yet it returns the error:

```
 Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

How can I ensure that this will work?

Comment: what datatype is it?

Comment: it is a datatype varchar

Comment: Maybe you have some data that can't be converted to a date. `CONVERT(DATE,Column,112)` should work otherwise

Comment: You should add the specific version of SQL Server that you are using as they support different functions for working with datetime data. Later versions support try_cast and try_convert for instance. `try_cast(column_name as date)` would return null for invalid rows, making them easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is a varchar, then you should be able to use CONVERT(DATE,[date_field], 112)

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE 
  (
    [date] varchar(10)
  )

INSERT INTO @dates([date])
VALUES('20110712'),('20141229'),('20100222'),('20140408'),('20131117'),('20130912'),('20140702'),('20110405')

SELECT CONVERT(date,[date],112) 
FROM @dates
```

Comment: why are you using the `101` format?, that's for `mm/dd/yyyy`, op is using `112` format (`yyyymmdd`)

Comment: Ya, I forgot to change that back before pasting it into this. I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: I was actually testing something out with the 101 format since it wasn't converting correctly. But selecting the convert statement with a CTE, and then selecting the info from the cte with another convert statement will convert to another format if you need to (if that makes any sense).

Comment: @HKImpact This is correct but the reason was that there was data not in the 8-char format that existed in the columnm, ie. 2015090H or 201403PL, essentailly a data issue. I had to use ISDATE() to filter out the problematic entries, then used what you presented